# AWS S3: How to plug in a dynamic file name in the S3 directory in COPY command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I have job in Redshift that is responsible for pulling 6 files every month from S3. File names follow a standard naming convention as "*file_label_MonthNameYYYY_Batch01.CSV*". I'd like to modify the below COPY command to change the file naming in the S3 directory dynamically so I won't have to hard code the Month Name and YYYY and batch number. Batch number ranges 1-6.

Currently, here is what I have which is not efficient:

```
COPY tbl_name ( column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 )
FROM 'S3://bucket_name/folder_name/Static_File_Label_July2021_Batch01.CSV'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id = xxx;aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx'
removequotes
EMPTYASNULL 
BLANKSASNULL 
DATEFORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY'
delimiter ','
IGNOREHEADER 1;

COPY tbl_name ( column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 )
FROM 'S3://bucket_name/folder_name/Static_File_Label_July2021_Batch02.CSV'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id = xxx;aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx'
removequotes
EMPTYASNULL 
BLANKSASNULL 
DATEFORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY'
delimiter ','
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

The dynamic file name shall change to *August2021_Batch01* & *August2021_Batch02* next month and so forth. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the files ever deleted? How do you run the command each month? (If you run it manually, then doing a Find & Replace is probably the easiest solution!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of approaches to this.  Which one is best for your case will depend on your circumstances.  You need a layer in your process that controls configuring SQL for each month.  Here are some ways to consider:

1. Use a manifest file - This file will have the S3 object names to
   load.  Your processing / file prep can update this file
2. Use a fixed load folder where the files are located for COPY, then
   move these files to perm storage location after COPY.
3. Use variables in you bench to set the Month value and replace this
   in when the SQL is issued to Redshift.
4. Write some code (Lambda?) to issue the SQL you are looking for
5. Last I checked you could leave the object name incomplete and all
   matching objects would be loaded.  Leave off the batch number and
   suffix and load all the files with one text change.

It is desirable to load multiple files with a COPY command (uses more nodes in parallel) and options 1, 2, and 5 do this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm learning ETL between Redshift & S3 and these are great ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the `FROM` location of files to load, you can specify a *partial filename*.

Here is an example from [COPY examples - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html):

> The following example loads the SALES table with tab-delimited data from lzop-compressed files in an Amazon EMR cluster. COPY loads every file in the `myoutput/` folder that begins with `part-`.

```sql
copy sales
from 'emr://j-SAMPLE2B500FC/myoutput/part-*' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
delimiter '\t' lzop;
```

Therefore, you could specify:

```
FROM 'S3://bucket_name/folder_name/Static_File_Label_July2021_*'
```

You would just need to change the Month & Year identifier. All files with that prefix would be loaded in one batch.